# securecrt python script open ssh with special port

Tags: python, ssh, port

How to use the python script which create a tab with special ssh port,
like this:

```
# $language = "python"
# $interface = "1.0"
host = '192.168.1.1'
user = 'test'
passwd = 'test'

def main():
    # how to use the port 22333 for ssh
    cmd = "/SSH2 /PASSWORD %s %s@%s port=22567" % (passwd, user, host)
    crt.Session.ConnectInTab(cmd, True)

main()
```

this is not working, but with the of the default port 22, it is working:

```
cmd = "/SSH2 /PASSWORD %s %s@%s" % (passwd, user, host)
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update cmd as follows:

```
cmd = "/SSH2 /PASSWORD %s %s@%s /P 22567" % (passwd, user, host)
```

or

```
cmd = "/SSH2 /PASSWORD %s %s@%s -p 22567" % (passwd, user, host)
```

reference: http://theory.uchicago.edu/~smaria/adam_ssh/SSH%20Secure%20Shell/documentation/SSH2.html

Comment: The first example is work! Reference:https://forums.vandyke.com/showthread.php?t=10680